# MS Word 2010: Vertical line to paragraph

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-excel-2010, text-formatting

I have a timeline of events in my CV, where each event is described by a single paragraph. Some paragraphs are logically enclosed by others (such as an internship during studies), which I want to symbolize by a vertical line on the left side.

Here's a sketch:

```
|  University of Awesome
|  Cool Classes and Great Grades
|
|| Internship at SwearShop Inc.
|| Slave away
|
|| Student Project
|| Researching Research about Research
|

|  University of Boredome
|  Bachelor in Beerdrinking
|
|| Another Sweatshop
|| Same story
|
```

(Important note: The lines should be running through, not as bullets or blocks)

What's the best way to accomplish this?

I have tried:

- Using tables. The width of cells in tables is limited by the empty space it must contain (symbolized by the circle with four 'pins' around), thus shading appropriately merged cells does not work. I thought about adding a vertical line or a box to the cell, but I cannot figure out how to fit the cell consistently (if they would be off by a consistent margin, that would work, too. It's a design question)
- Using paragraph formatting. Since you can add borders to a paragraph, I tried it, but this only works on a single 'level', since obviously you cannot embed paragraphs within each other

  - Using bar-tabs. You can add tabstops and set them to display a bar. However I seem to be unable to configure them to match my design (such as color and thickness)

I am trying to to this in Word, but I am also happy to use Latex.

Thanks for your input!

Answer (score 0):

My choice would be to use formatting styles for lists (outlining), e.g. Level1, Level2 etc. Set the format of the style as you want, with leader, color etc. to keep it consistent.

That said, most CV's and résumés are evaluated by PC applications before a person looks at them. Keep it simple to have the best chance of being forwarded top a human. [BTW, did you intern at SwearShop or at SweatShop? It may be pedantic to criticize a humorous example, but *any* error on a *real* CV might cause HR to regard it negatively.]

Comment: Thanks, lists sound like a great idea! How exactly would you get the 'embedded' paragraphs to have two bars on the side though? 
Btw. I appreciate your input on the computer scanning of CVs, I haven't thought about that yet :)

Comment: Each Word list style can be set to the format you want, e.g. left border, marker symbol, such as bullet or caret, and you could possibly find a Unicode character with one, two or three vertical lines. Again, though, a creative CV may not be as effective as a standard, dull, format.

Comment: I understand now what your idea is, and I clarified my question. I'm looking for one line, that logically 'encloses' the other paragraphs. Sorry for the misunderstanding!

Comment: A paragraph style can be set for outline completely surrounding text, or on any 1, 2 or 3 sides, at a width and color of your choice.